# Regular expressions in c++ STL

Tags: c++, regex, stl

Is there any native library in STL which is tested and works without any extra compiler options?
I tried to use `<regex>`, but the compiler outputs this:

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.3/regex:40, from main.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.3/c++0x_warning.h:36:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

Comment: Why do you not want to add options to the command line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

G++ 4.3 (and presumably later versions as well) is just being careful about the header files for maximum standards conformance.

If you're programming in C++98 (the current standard that's been around for a while), then regular expression support was added in tech report 1, and the and the header files are in a special `tr1` directory, and the contents are in a special namespace `std::tr1`.

In the new C++0x standard, the regular expression support has been merged into the standard library, so it can be found in the header `regex` and namespace `std`.

G++ makes sure that you use the right version for the `--std=` version you specified on the command line, even though internally they're both the same implementation.

So to make regex work without switching to `--std=c++0x`, just

```
#include <tr1/regex>
```

Comment: Nice, this works (it outputs no warnings or errors when compiling), but how should i write the pattern itself?
regex pattern("[^-]-[^-]"); is not working... :( compiler says "unknown" type - regex

Comment: That's a separate question. Ask it separately.

Comment: fantastic! I can use  C11!

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that regular expression support was added in C++0x, so there are no STL things that support it until then. If you don't want to use c++0x, you could use Boost instead, but that's not in the STL.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using Boost.Regex instead of the c++0x headers.
Also the STL is not the same thing as the standard library. It used to stand for "Standard Template Library" back when that was an offering of SGI. The standard library did not adopt everything int the STL (rope and slist) and covers much more ground than the STL did (iostreams, all the tr1, tr2, and c++0x headers).